# How to deploy to multiple environments with webpack using msdeploy

Tags: deployment, angular, webpack, teamcity, msdeploy

I've got a .NET WebAPI solution, and a UI built in Angular2 RC4 (angular-cli webpack version). I'm confused about how to deploy these to different environments, especially configuration parameters - there seems to be a mismatch between the .NET way and the UI way of doing things, which I don't quite get.

Here's how I've got it currently in TeamCity. The WebAPI solution is built once only, and is configured **at deploy time**. The various configuration parameters the project needs (such as connection strings, endpoints etc.) are stored in web.config. When I deploy to my test environment using MSDeploy, I pass in `setParam` arguments to the MSDeploy command line which replaces the connection strings and endpoints in the web.config with those values. When I deploy to production, I use the same build but pass in different arguments to the `setParam` in the command line.

This approach makes sense to me because I know that the exact same build is going from one environment to the next, the only difference being the parameters I specifically told it to set for each environment. Super.

With Angular2 and webpack it looks like a different approach is needed. When I build my project (with `ng build -prod`) it minimizes and bundles my HTML and Javascript files into 3 or 4 files, along with gzipped versions of those files. This is great for reducing file size and increasing speed of my website, but there is no way to "inject" configuration parameters into these gzip files like there is with MSDeploy's `setParam`. Everywhere I've seen that mentions webpack is showing webpack.dev.config.js and webpack.prod.config.js. But doesn't that mean we need to build a different bundle for each environment? And actually with Angular2 the webpack bit is considered "a black box" and it's not possible to supply your own webpack.config file anyway.

The only workaround I can think of is to use TeamCity's "File Content Replacer" on the "main.1234abcd6946c6a08519.bundle.js" to replace my configuration parameters with the values for that environment, then gzip that file - overwriting the one created by webpack.

But this is horrible, so I'm looking for any better suggestions?

Comment: you cant gzip a file... I think you mean minification

Comment: Your webpack config is just a node app. Pass parameters into the application from the CLI

Comment: @cgatian By "gzip that file" I meant zip it up in gzip format using 7zip or something. To create the bundle I need to run "ng build -prod" which doesn't accept any webpack related parameters unfortunately.

Comment: well damn. Didn't know that

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience with webpack or if this is better than your workaround but you can use the TextFile kind of setParam entry to alter any file in your project using Regex find/replace at deploy time.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569084(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: I do use that method in another part of my deploy, but I'm not sure it can work inside a gzip file :(

Comment: It can't.  I was unclear how the gzip file was used.  Sorry.  The only other idea I had was you could create a version of the gzip for each environment and then use parameterization to reference the right one at deploy time.

Comment: Yeah that's what I've started doing now. It's probably fine, just a different way of thinking to what I'm used to. Thanks

Comment: If this answer was helpful please don't forget to mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I went with creating a separate package for each environment. I added a build step that replaces my API URL on localhost in src\app\environment.ts, with the appropriate URL for that environment, then it runs `npm build -prod` and then MSDeploy to create the package. I do this for all environments I want to target.

Here's the script:

```
REM =====CREATE TEST PACKAGE==================================================

REM backup the environment file
ren src\app\environment.ts environment.ts.bak
copy /Y src\app\environment.ts.bak src\app\environment.ts


REM replace localhost in environment file with the TEST environment URL
"%env.FART%" src\app\environment.ts http://localhost:12345 %TEST.api.url%


REM build using this environment
call npm run build-prod


REM restore backup environment file
del /Q src\app\environment.ts
ren src\app\environment.ts.bak environment.ts


REM create TEST package
"%env.MSDEPLOY%"  ^
 -verb:sync  ^
 -source:contentPath="%teamcity.build.workingDir%\dist"  ^
 -dest:package="%teamcity.build.checkoutDir%\Package_TEST.zip"




REM =====CREATE PROD PACKAGE==================================================

REM backup the environment file
ren src\app\environment.ts environment.ts.bak
copy /Y src\app\environment.ts.bak src\app\environment.ts


REM replace localhost in environment file with the PROD environment URL
"%env.FART%" src\app\environment.ts http://localhost:12345 %PROD.api.url%


REM build using this environment
call npm run build-prod


REM restore backup environment file
del /Q src\app\environment.ts
ren src\app\environment.ts.bak environment.ts


REM create PROD package
"%env.MSDEPLOY%"  ^
 -verb:sync  ^
 -source:contentPath="%teamcity.build.workingDir%\dist"  ^
 -dest:package="%teamcity.build.checkoutDir%\Package_PROD.zip"
```

By the way, `%env.FART%` is the location of [`fart.exe`](http://fart-it.sourceforge.net/) which is a great find/replace tool that I use to replace one string in a file with another.